# Identifying the dependence of various time-independent wavefunctions

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I'm tasked with finding the variables that each of the following wavefunctions depends on: (1) a free particle in 2 space (2) a free particle in 3 space (3) a hydrogen atom (4) a lithium atom.

for situations (1) and (2) I get $\psi(x,y)$ and $\psi(x,y,z)$. However, regarding situations (3) and (4), I'm unsure how to proceed - advice?

Comment: Hydrogen atom has one nucleus (in 3D space) and one electron (in 3D space). Lithium atom one nucleus and 3 electrons. Help yourself!
Once done, try some coordinate transformations from laboratory frame to something more local.

Comment: @ssavec I would love to figure this out myself, but I don't know how to interpret one nucleus and one electron in terms of a wavefunction.

Comment: you do not need to write the wavefunction, just find the variables. So 3 coordinates for electron and 3 coordinates for nucleus.

Comment: @ssavec wait, but spin... ;)

Comment: @ssavec So I would have $\psi(r_e,\theta_e,\phi_e)$ for the electron and $\psi(r_n,\theta_n,\phi_n)$ for the neutron?

Comment: @Jay: almost, one wavefunction to rule them all.  $\psi(r_n,\theta_n,\phi_n,r_e,\theta_e,\phi_e )$

Comment: Okay I think I get it. So then lithium would have a wavefunction composed of  $r,\theta,\phi$ for 4 objects, specifically one nucleus and three electrons?

Comment: As @Wildcat mentioned there is an additional spin coordinate $\omega$ for the nucleus and each of the electrons, which complicates matters, but neglecting that you're right.